# how to use pointer character to locate pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, reverse

4   12  C:\Users\Nishu\OneDrive\Desktop\test\Untitled1.cpp  [Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[5]' to 'char*' in initialization

i tried to reverse and array using pointer but it shows an array, i tried it with and without '&', without it, it only scan 2 values and then reverse it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[5];
char *p = &name;
int i;
printf("Enter  the array");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%c",p);
    p++;
}
p--;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%c",*(p));
    p--;
}
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&name` is a pointer to the *array*. It will have the type `char (*)[5]`.

You want a pointer to the first *element* of the array, which is `&name[0]`.

And please remember (or learn) that plain `name` will by itself *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

So the initialization of `p` should be

```
char *p = name;
```

---

There are a few other problems in your code though. For example the `scanf` format `%c` will *not* skip leading space, like the newline added by the Enter. If you give one character at a time as input, followed by the Enter key then the second character you read will be a newline. You need to add a leading space to tell `scanf` to skip white-space: `" %c"`.

Also note that you don't create a *string*. You have an array of characters, but you never add the string null-terminator `'\0'` character. So while your use of the array is fine, you can never pass it to any function expecting a null-terminated string.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the new line concept. Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a character array with 5 elements.

```
char name[5];
```

So the pointer expression `&name` has the pointer type `char ( * )[5]`. This expression is used to initialize a pointer of the type `char *`

```
 char *p = &name;
```

However there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types.

Instead you need to write

```
 char *p = name;
```

In this case the array designator `name` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

As for the task to output an array in the reverse order using a pointer then the declaration of the variable `i` in this case is redundant. You could write

```
enum { N = 5 };
char name[N];
char *p = name;

printf( "Enter  the array: " );

for ( ; p != name + N; ++p )
{
    scanf( " %c", p );
}

while ( p != name ) printf( "%c", *--p) ;
putchar( '\n' );
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string in this call of `scanf`

```
scanf( " %c", p );
       ^^^
```

It allows to skip white space characters. That is if the user will enter a namd pressing the Enter ley after each entered character as for example

```
B
o
b
b
y
```

then the array will contain the sequence `Bobby`. Without the leading space in the format string the array will contain also new line characters `'\n'`.